# Recyclerview is not displaying items (no adapter,attached skipping layout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

HI so im making this File manager app for my portfolio , im fairly now to android programming , im trying to display files and folder via Recyclerview . but for some DAMN reason it is not showing list of items ..like fragment is switching default layout to fragment containing recyclerview but that recyclerview is not displaying the item-layout. PLEASE HELP

thanks a LOT in advance (this issue is driving me insane)

EDIT: there is an error saying "no adapter attached,skipping layout", and YES i have seen all stack overflow threads regarding it .. my case is a bit different

here is the MainActivity

```
    public class FilesDisplayActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_files_display);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

and here the Fragment Replacing its Layout

```
public class FilesDisplayFragment extends Fragment {

   
   

 
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataHolder;
     int fileFoundCount;
    File dir;
     File[] files;

    public FilesDisplayFragment() {
      

    }

    
    
    
    public static FilesDisplayFragment newInstance() {
        FilesDisplayFragment fragment = new FilesDisplayFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
        final String rootpath=String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
         dir = new File(rootpath);
         files= dir.listFiles();
        if(files.length>0){
            Log.i("FILESNOTNULL","TRUE");
        }

        dataHolder=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i =0;i<fileFoundCount;i++){
            dataHolder.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.folder,files[i].getAbsolutePath(),1,1,"0/0/0"));
            //this is just a test data

        }




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_display, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.files_rec_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        

        MyItemRecyclerViewListAdapter adapter = new MyItemRecyclerViewListAdapter(dataHolder);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        return view;
    }
}
```

and here is the adapter

```
public class FilesDisplayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilesDisplayAdapter.myViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataholder;

    public FilesDisplayAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList) {
        this.dataholder = arrayList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.files_or_folders,parent,false);


        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.img.setImageResource(dataholder.get(position).getImg());
        holder.filename.setText(String.valueOf(dataholder.get(position).getFileName()));
        holder.filesize.setText(String.valueOf(dataholder.get(position).getFilesize()));
        holder.subitems.setText(String.valueOf(dataholder.get(position).getNoOfItems()));
        holder.dateCreated.setText(String.valueOf(dataholder.get(position).getDateCreated()));

        Log.i("DEBUG", String.valueOf(holder.filename.getText()));


        Log.i("Message",dataholder.get(position).getFileName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("DATASIZE",String.valueOf(dataholder.size()));
        return dataholder.size();
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView filename,filesize,subitems,dateCreated;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            
            img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fof_imagview);
            filename=itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_view);
            filesize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fof_size);
            subitems=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fof_no_of_items);
            dateCreated=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fof_date_created);




        }
    }
}
```

xml of original activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    tools:context=".FilesDisplayActivity">



</FrameLayout>
```

xml of fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.FilesDisplayFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/files_rec_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#EAE6E6" />
</FrameLayout>
```

xml of item view holder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >




    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/fof_imagview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                android:src="@drawable/folder">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/file_name_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
                        android:text="File Name"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fof_size"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/file_name"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text="Size" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fof_no_of_items"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                        android:text="no Of items"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fof_date_created"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                        android:text="Date Created"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

LOG file exceeding the character capacity .all i could find there is "no adapter attached , skipping layout " ..else seemed fine

Comment: In your line `MyItemRecyclerViewListAdapter adapter... ` is `dataHolder` filled with items? I know onCreate is called before onCreateView, but just in case.

Comment: no adapter attached is not an error but a warning because you call `notifyDataSetChange` after adding the adapter to the recyclerView. but you have an empty list mayebe you have te check the dataHolder if is'not  empty

Comment: yeah ..it seems if i set height and width to wrap content or match parent of the item layout layout is not showing , but when i set it to a specific value . it is showing . also image (r.drawable.folder) is not displaying for some reason